# Any way to define ALL variables within function as property of this?

Tags: javascript, this

I know this may sound a little absurd, but I'm looking for a way to define every variable within a function as a property of `this`. I'm looking for any hack, any way possible to be able to have some way to track variables within a function (i.e. add them to the `this` object) without having to actually preface every single variable definition with `this.`. Is there a way? Is this possible with `Proxy`?

```
function () {
  // declare a variable
  var hello = 'hi'
  return this
}

let {hello} = function()
console.log(hello) // hi
```

For example this works:

```
function hi () { this.hello = true; return this }
hi.bind({})() // { hello: true }
```

What I want is a way to have all variables defined within `hi` to be added to the `this` object when they are defined.

Comment: Isn't `this` a singular nature? A reference to the function owner? Any variable can reference `this`, but it references one thing only. It can be changed by `.call` or `.apply`.

Comment: You can't do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking for the worst hack imaginable? Sure, everything is possible:

```
function example () {
  with(horrible(this)) {
    var hello = 'hi';
  }
}
var x = new example;
x.hello; // 'hi'


function horrible(target) {
  return new Proxy(target, {
    has() { return true; }, // contains all variables you could ever wish for!
    get(_, k) { return k in target ? target[k] : (1,eval)(k) }
  });
}
```

The proxy claims to contain all names that could ever be used as a variable in the `with` scope. This basically leads to all assignments of undeclared or `var`-declared variables create properties on the target (unless you use `let` or `const`, they'll be truly local to the block scope).
However, for variable lookup everything that is not a target property will be resolved in the global scope (using global `eval`) as the original scope cannot be retained when the proxy said it can deliver all variables.

Comment: Much cleaner that my answer! But references to outer variables won't work, e.g `console.log('foo')`

Comment: @Oriol I was just fixing that :-)

Comment: @Bergi any way to include vars declared with `let` and `const`?

Comment: @ThomasReggi No, but that's actually quite useful if you need some variables that should not become properties. If you really want complete control, get the function's code (via `.toString`) and do static analysis or transpilation.

Comment: @Bergi check this http://astexplorer.net/#/fIw4JAexWk/2 credit =>  https://twitter.com/drewml

Comment: @ThomasReggi Yeah, something like that. Though you probably want to do those assignments at the end of the function. Or just replace all the references to any variables by property accessors.

Comment: Since you use an indirect call to eval to resolve in the global scope, wouldn't `window[k]` also do the trick?

Comment: @Oriol Not in non-browser environments or for `let` and `const`.

Comment: will this feature be depreciated by any chance ignoring 'use strict'?

Comment: @William For web compatibility reasons the behaviour of `with` in sloppy mode will probably never be deprecated

Comment: Hey @Bergi, is there any way to include `function` declarations as well? As in
`function foo() {}` so that it also gets assigned to the proxy target.

Comment: And the same for IIFE's inside the eval'ed code? For example `(function() { var foo = 1; })();` so that `foo` also gets assigned to the proxy target.

Comment: @LordTribual No, `function` declarations don't work, probably because of [hoisting rules for block-level functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31419897/1048572) (and we cannot use strict mode). And no, it's certainly impossible to affect the private scope of IIFEs.

Answer (score 3):

You can, kind of. But it's a very very dirty hack which requires you to

- Wrap the code inside a `with` statement, which has performance costs, is bad practice, and is not allowed in strict mode.
- Use evil `eval` to get the values of the variables.
- There can be false positives. Only `var` variables are detected, but not `let` or `const` ones.

```js
function func() {
  // The proxy will detect the variables
  var vars = [];
  var proxy = new Proxy({}, {
    has(target, property) {
      vars.push(property);
    }
  });
  with(proxy) {
    // Place your code here
    var hello = 'hi';
  }
  // Assign the variables as properties
  for (var property of vars)
    this[property] = eval(property);
  return this;
}
let {hello} = func.call({});
console.log(hello) // hi
```