# Running JS code in limited context

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run **trusted** JS code in an "isolated" context.
Basically came up with this method:

```js
function limitedEval(src, context) {
    return (function() {
        with(this) {
            return eval(src) 
        }
    }).call(context)
}
```

This works great, however when the script is using the `var` keyword it is stored in the *execution context* as opposed to the provided context in the with statement (which I understand is by design). So for example, the following code doesn't work:

```js
var ctx = {};
limitedEval('var foo = "hello"', ctx);
limitedEval('alert(foo)', ctx); // error: foo is undefined
```

I'd like to be able to call limitedEval() multiple times and reuse the context. Is that possible?

Comment: "Trusted" and `eval()` never belong in the same discussion.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: he means that eval is not a secured function and can introduce multiple security issues. You should be looking into something like https://github.com/ternjs/acorn

Comment: There really are extremely limited use cases for `eval()`. It should generally be avoided.

Comment: @ScottMarcus They belong in exactly the same discussion - using `eval` *requires* that the executed code is trusted.

Comment: You might be interested in [this solution^H^H^H^H^H hack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41050254/1048572)

Comment: What environment are you running this in? Node has the [vm module](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) for *exactly* this purpose

Comment: Browser environment. Global context is the window object.

Comment: `with` and `eval` in the same function... Do you want to upset Douglas Crockford?

Comment: For browser environment webworkers may be a way to do this. You can simply create an eval service with a webworker and run code in a separate thread.

Comment: Got it working, but definitely feels like a hack:
https://jsfiddle.net/2g0nkf7z/7/

Comment: @Dandan That's because `alert` does not directly refer to the global variable, but is accessed as a property of the proxy, and is called as a method on it - leading to an error. `alert.call(null, hello)` or `console.log(hello)` work as they're not plain calls. In your case you probably want to restrict access to global variables anyway so I don't see an issue with that, but yes it's just a hack and will need more hacking to work as expected…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a very interesting problem. The problem with your code is that you generate new function every time you execute `limitedEval`. This means that whatever variables you create using `var` keyword, will only exist within the context of that function. What you really need is to have 1 function per context and reuse that function's context. The most obvious way to do that is by using [generators](https://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators). Generators are essentially functions that can be paused and then restarted.

```js
// IIFE to store gen_name
var limitedEval = function() {
    // Symbol for generator property so we don't pollute `ctx` namespace
    var gen_name = Symbol();

    return function limitedEval(src, context) {
        if(!(gen_name in context)) {
            // Generator that will run eval and pause til getting the next source code
            var generator = function * () {
                with(this) {
                    while(true) {
                        yield eval( yield );
                    }
                }
            };

            context[gen_name] = generator.call(context);

            // Initially, we need to execute code until reaching the first `yield`
            context[gen_name].next();
        }

        // First, send the source to the `eval`
        context[gen_name].next( src );

        // Second, get the `eval` result
        return context[gen_name].next().value;
    };
}();
```

And now you can call

```js
var ctx = {};
limitedEval('var foo = "hello"', ctx);
limitedEval('alert(foo);', ctx);
```

Every `limitedEval` call will now reuse whatever generator function it will find on the provided `ctx` object. If the function doesn't exist, it will create it and put it on the `ctx` object. Because you now have only one function per `ctx`, it will reuse the function's context when creating variables with `var` keyword. Note: you will not be able to look up those variables via the `ctx` object, because they will only exist within the function's context.

I'm not entirely sure if you can achieve the same result without using generators.

**Edit**: others made great suggestions so I replaced randomly generated property with `Symbol` and did `with(this)` instead of `with(context)`

Comment: You should use a `Symbol()` to prevent polluting the context namespace!

Comment: I'd recommend to make the generator not an IIFE but a named generator function, and to use `with(this)` and `yield eval(yield)` to avoid any scope variables in the `eval`

Comment: Bonus question: is there a way to achieve this in strict mode? with keyword is restricted.

Comment: i really don't see how this is supposed to created a limited context. `with` keyword does not restrict access to the parent scope. It just looks up names in the context first. You may want to use a `Proxy` object in `with` that if the target doesn't have the property it just returns `undefined`