# Truly safe `eval` using ES6 `Proxy` and `with`?

Tags: javascript, security, eval

It's a well known fact that neither Javascript's `eval` keyword nor `Function` objects created from strings should ever for any reason be used to run untrusted code.

However, I'm wondering if ES6 proxies change that. Consider:

```
let env = {eval: eval};
let proxy = new Proxy(env, { has: () => true });
with(proxy) {eval('...')}
```

The proxy object pretends to have all possible properties, which means that it blocks the search of higher scopes. Within the `with` block, any properties not set on `env` appear `undefined`, and any global properties set inside the with block are actually set on `env`.

This seems to allow me to set up a completely controlled and isolated environment for the `eval`ed code to run in. What are the risks?

Here are a few concerns I can see:

1. Don't put anything that references `window`, or `document`, or `localStorage`, or anything else sensitive, into `env`.
2. Don't put any mutable object into `env` unless you're ok with untrusted code mutating it.

   - Solution: make deep copies if necessary.
3. Code inside the `with` block has no access to *anything* outside it. If it needs things like `Math`, `Object`, or `String`, they have to be put in `env` - which means these can be modified by malicious code. Even the `eval` function in my minimal example above can be modified.

   - Solution: Create proxies for these objects to white-list read-only access to specific properties.

As long as you follow these guidelines, is this actually safe? Are there other concerns?

Comment: `while(true);`.

Comment: You also forgot access to `this` (…`.window`, `.document`, `.anything`) and `(function(){}).constructor("…")()`

Comment: @Dandan is [doing a very similar thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43989742/1048572). Do you work together?

Comment: Because I have fun with messing around: `({}).constructor.defineProperty({}.constructor.getPrototypeOf({}),"get",{value(){this.has=()=>false;this.get=undefined;},writable:true}); whoops; document.write("I am a bad guy. Good luck!")`

Answer (score 3):

It is quite easy to break out of this environment, via a number of different ways, some or all of which might possibly be mitigated:

1. Object, Array, and RegExp literals (`{ }`, `[ ]`, and `/.../`) are unimpeded by the Proxy and allow access to (and mutation of) `Object.protoype`, `Array.prototype`, and `RegExp.prototype`. You can, however, lock these with `Object.freeze` before running your `eval`.
2. You must `delete env.eval` within your evaled string, or else the script can execute global code by renaming the `eval` function like `globalEval = eval;`
3. You cannot prevent the creation of new functions, which may use a global `this` object: `(function () { this.globalFunc(); })()`. Possibly enforcing strict mode by appending `"use strict";` to your evaled input could eliminate this escape vector.
4. Any access to the `Function` constructor (via `(a=>a).__proto__.constructor`) allows execution of global code. You can `delete Function.constructor` to prevent this, but there may be other ways to access `Function`.