# Validating AST using Babel to use eval safely on User Input Code

Tags: javascript, parsing, babeljs, eval, abstract-syntax-tree

We have a NodeJS Application where a User can input Javascript code. The JS code needs to be run in the same environment using `eval`.
Now, as it has been recommended almost everywhere to avoid using `eval` (especially on User Input), so initially I tried creating my own Parser (using [Peg.JS](https://pegjs.org/)). But, this is a difficult task (especially for people like me who have limited exposure to things like Parsers, AST, grammar, etc).

Then, I got to know that we can use [Babel Parser](https://babel.dev/docs/babel-parser) to create AST of a piece of Code. So, I created a small piece of code to simulate the same and validate each Node using [Babel Traverse](https://babel.dev/docs/babel-traverse). It "seems" to be working fine:

```js
const parser = require("@babel/parser");
const _traverse = require("@babel/traverse");
// Traverse issue: Thanks to: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/13855#issuecomment-945123514
const traverse = _traverse.default;

const unsafeMethods = ["require", "eval"];

const sourceCode = `var a = 123;
var b = 456;
require("fs");
// Commented require("fs");
console.log("Sum of " + a + " and " + b + " is " + (a+b));

var c = function(message){
    console.log(">>> " + message);
};
c("Finished. Bye.");`;

const ast = parser.parse(sourceCode);
var unsafe = false;
traverse(ast, {
    enter(path) {
        if (path.node.type === "Identifier" && unsafeMethods.indexOf(path.node.name) != -1) {
            unsafe = true;
        }
    },
});
if (unsafe) {
    console.log("Code is Unsafe.");
} else {
    console.log("Code is Safe.");
}
```

**But, I'm in doubt whether the approach is legit or not. Also, if I need to make it more secure, what else should I add to the same?**

Few References that I came across related to this:

- [Using ast and whitelists to make python's eval() safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523516/using-ast-and-whitelists-to-make-pythons-eval-safe)
- [Restricting eval() to a narrow scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543533/restricting-eval-to-a-narrow-scope)
- [calling eval() in particular context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403108/calling-eval-in-particular-context)
- [Running JS code in limited context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989742/running-js-code-in-limited-context)
- AST Explorer where I was trying: https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/c0a93ae3582d5fb023e04c4db87d83ac/aad578c834339d3a6f8bac5207e0123b7c19d834

Comment: The above might be able to identify `require("fs");` as unsafe - but does it do the same thing for `window["req"+"uire"]("fs");` ...?

Comment: Yes it works, if I also add `window` to the `unsafeMethods` list. Though, I forgot to mention that this is meant for Backend.