# Way to intercept with's property lookup/check?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, with-statement, es6-proxy

**Note:** This isn't a question about best practices. The [`with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) is obviously something we should avoid in regular JS usage. I'm interested in its behaviour because I'm writing a simple [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) and seeing how I can push JavaScript's limits to make certain features work.

---

Consider the following code:

```
var obj = {prop:0};
with(obj) { prop = 1; }
// obj.prop === 1
```

Whenever we use a variable inside the `with` block (like `prop`, above), it first looks to see if that variable is a property of `obj`. If it is, then it basically converts that variable to `obj.prop`.

However, if the variable is not found within `obj`, then the JS engine surfs up the scope chain looking for `prop` until it reaches the global object as a last resort:

```
var obj = {};
with(obj) { prop = 1; }
// obj.prop === undefined
// window.prop === 1
```

**Here's my question:** In the above example, the JS engine looks for `prop` within `obj`. Is there a way to intercept this lookup? I'd like to "trick" the JS engine (in a spec-compliant way, of course) into thinking that `obj` has every property in existence, so that all variables references withing the `with` statement are interpreted as `obj.variable`. Basically, I want this behaviour:

```
var obj = {};
with(obj) { prop = 1; }
// obj.prop === 1
```

I thought this would be as simple as proxying `obj` and intercepting `get`s, since (I figured) the engine would do a `get` to see is `obj` has `prop`. I thought that I could simply return something other than `undefined`, and then the `with` would treat `obj` as having all properties:

```
var prox = new Proxy({}, {
    set(target, property, value) { target[property] = value; },
    get(target, property) { return target[property] !== undefined ? target[property] : null; },
});
with(prox) { prop = 1; }
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: So you don't really have a question?

Comment: I have a question and an answer ;)

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41050254/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

While writing this question I discovered the `has` trap  of the `Proxy` which was the answer to my question. So here's how you achieve the behaviour I was looking for:

```
var prox = new Proxy({}, {
    has(target, property) { return true; },
});
with(prox) { prop = 1; }
// prox.prop === 1
```

**Edit:** Just a note that playing around with these dark arts can cause Chrome's DevTools to [crash in certain situations](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=724858). Just in case that saves anyone time debugging.

Comment: For those interested, that's because of [`GetIdentifierReference`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-getidentifierreference), step 3. It checks whether the environment record has a binding with that name which in case of an object environment record means to check [whether the property exists](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-object-environment-records-hasbinding-n).

Comment: MDN has some useful information on the [*Poxy* object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), e.g. not supported in IE.