# Need to call a function that has been lost to scope

Tags: javascript, function, object, scope

I have an object that is defined in another file that I cannot edit.
I need to call a function that was defined within it, but was not set as a method.
My test does not work since callMe does not exist in my scope.

```
// Example
function ObjectCreator()
{
    this.name = "I am an object";


    var callMe = function()
    {
        console.log("You did it");
    }

    this.DontCallMe = function()
    {
        console.log("You should not have called me");
        callMe();
    }

    return this;
}
```

My File

```
// My attempt

var foo = new ObjectCreator();

foo.test = function()
{
    // throws not defined error
    callMe();
};

foo.test();
```

How can I call callMe() without editing the original file to make it public?

Comment: I think you can't but you why don't you use the "DontCallMe" method ?

Comment: Because in the actual object it does things that I don't want done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible. This function will be defined only inside the constructor, or other scopes nested on it - this how lexical scope works.

See: [Getting All Variables In Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051678/getting-all-variables-in-scope)