# pass ALL local variables from Jade to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pug

I can find solutions to pass local variables from jade to javascript, for example:

```
script.
  var myVar = `#{myVar}`;
script(src=src)
```

But since I want to use my jade template for many views, with different sets of variables, I wonder if it is possible to pass ALL available local variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051678/getting-all-variables-in-scope) it doesn't look like there's a clean way of getting all variables in scope.

In which case you're best off gathering all variables you want to pass to your jade/pug in a single object and then pass that object to the pug file.

```
const holder = {};

holder.one = 1;
holder.two = 2;

pug.compile(page, holder);
```

You can then do

```
script.
  var one= `#{one}`;
script(src=src)
```