# Given an array/list of variable names, print all the variable names as string if the variable is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

What would be a simple way other than having many if...else functions and hardcoding the variable names as string.
Let say we have 10 variables that may or may not contain some values. I want to be able to return a list of all those variable names that are null.

Instead of doing:

```
if (x == null) return "x"
```

for all the variables, is there a better way that I can do this? Looking for javascript/jquery or underscore methods.

Comment: If you need to refer to "variables" dynamically, make them properties in an object.

Comment: Where are the variables? Are they object properties or something?

Comment: and why you dont want to use if loop? Any specific reason?

Comment: @Salketer They are just simple variables that are defined in the application. var x= something, y = somethingelse ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get a list of variables out of thin air, so you would need to test on an object's properties.

This should work on objects. It takes all keys and filter them through isNUll

```
console.log(_.filter(_.keys(object),(key)=>{
    return _.isNull(object[key]);
}));
```

You can read more about getting the impossibility (or very improbability) of getting current scope variables: [Getting All Variables In Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051678/getting-all-variables-in-scope)

Answer (score 1):

If you follow @Pointy's advice in the comments and make your variables properties of an object, you will be able to do the following :

```
const person = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: null,
    age: null
}

for(let prop in person) {
    if(person[prop] === null)  console.log(prop + ' is null');
}
```

And if you want to check the values of some globally declared variables, it won't be much less verbose but much more elegant than multiple ifs :

```
['x', 'y', 'z'].map((propName) => {
    if(window[propName] === null || window[propName] === undefined) 
        console.log(prop + ' is not defined');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should maintain an object of the variables `x,y` like this (in ES6 for example)

```
var obj = {
  x,
  y
}
```

And then filter out the null properties

```
Object.keys(obj).filter(k => obj[k] === null)
```

An array of null variable names will be returned.