# Mongo shell: list all declared variables

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Is there a way in the mongo shell to list all variables that have been created so far.
E.g. when I create a bunch of variables like

```
var myDocument = db.myCollection.find({"awards.wins":8});
var b = 20;
var a = 21;
```

how can I list all variables that have already been created in this session so far,  or how can I list all variables that exist?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting All Variables In Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051678/getting-all-variables-in-scope)

Comment: A hack would be to go through the history of your [Mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#files)