# Shorthand Method to Create Property in Object only if Variable is defined

Tags: javascript, object, variables, properties, assign

Looking for a shorthand method to assign properties to an object ONLY when the assigning variable is defined.

Current Code:

```
let count = {}, one = 1, two = 2, four = 4;
if (one) count.one = one; 
if (two) count.two = two; 
if (three) count.three = three; 
if (four) count.four = four;
```

Result:
count = { one: 1, two: 2, four: 4 }

Normally, I would try this:

```
let count = { one, two, three, four }
```

However, it complains when three is undefined...

Is there a better method to shorthand assign only when defined?

What I cannot have:

count = { one: 1, two: 2, three: undefined, four: 4 }

Comment: What's wrong with `undefined`? Any code that uses the object should work the same with not defined properties and `undefined`-valued properties.

Comment: @Bergi It's being saved to disk in JSON format and occupies space when assigned a null or undefined.  I also wanted to make the JSON uncluttered for easy visual viewing.  I was trying to avoid that clutter.  But you are somewhat right, the main purpose was to save coding line and make it look neat in the program.  I ended up pre-defining all variables to null and just using the let count = {one, two, three, four} in the end, and living with the additional clutter.  pre-defining to null allowed me to declare the whole thing without errors.

Comment: No! JSON only knows `null`, it does not represent `undefined`. A property with the value `undefined` will not show up in the `JSON.stringify` result, it's treated as if the property had never been created. Do not initialise the variables with `null`, just declare them (defaulting to `undefined`), and it will work out of the box.

Comment: True enough, but I still have the problem of declaring then stringifying the variable for JSON in one nice elegant line of code without getting the error message of a variable being undefined, unless you know a better way to JSON.stringify({one, two, three, four}) when three is undefined.

Comment: If the variable has the value `undefined`, you won't get an error message - `JSON.stringify({one, two, three, four})` works just fine. If the variable is not *declared*, that's a bug in the code - you need to declare it with `let`/`const`/`var` before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it complains when three is undefined...

No, it will only complain when the variable `three` is not *declared*, not when it has the value `undefined`. You can easily fix that:

```js
let one = 1, two = 2, three /* = 3 */, four = 4;

const count = JSON.stringify({one, two, three, four});
console.log(count);
```

If the variable is not used anywhere, you can just omit it, as it never would have any value. If the variable is used (assigned a value somewhere), you need to declare it anyway in strict mode.

Comment: Oh...  I stand correct.  Good job.  Thanks, I believe this is what I needed.  I have upvoted your answer as the correct one, but since my reputation is below 15, it will not show.  I think however if you upvote my question, I might have the reputation points needed at that point.

Comment: All I need now is to remove that eyesore of {} when none of the variables have a value.  Thanks, it worked perfectly.

Comment: For checking whether the object is empty, you can either compare the JSON string against `"{}"`, or use `const obj = {…}; if (Object.values(obj).every(v => v != null)) …`

Comment: Ah....  thank you also for the tutorial on accepting the answer.  Done and accepted.  One more thing...  When scraping the site, I sometimes get an empty element, and would prefer to not create an object property when that happens...  ie, count.one = $('#one').val();   Any easy one-liner way to NOT create the property if the value is empty?

Comment: You mean treating the empty string as undefined? You can do that using `count.one = $('#one').val() || undefined;`. Still creates the property though, if you don't want that you won't get around an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to check if the variable is undefined and, if this variable is undefined, you don't add it to the object.

```
var count = {}, one = 1, two = 2, four = 4;

function addToObject(value){
 if(typeof value === 'undefined') return
 this.count[value] = value;
}

this.addToObject(this.one);
this.addToObject(this.two);
this.addToObject(this.three);
this.addToObject(this.four);
this.addToObject(this.five);

console.log(this.count);
// {1: 1, 2: 2, 4: 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

This only work when the variables are global and can be access by `window[name]`
You need a string list that contain variable name you trying to get

```js
var target_list = ["one", "two", "three", "four"],
    count = {},
    one = 1, two = 2, four = 4;

for (let target of target_list) {
    if (window[target]) {
        count[target] = window[target];
    } else {
        console.log(`variable [${target}] not found`);
    }
}

console.log(count);
```

[Getting All Variables In Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051678/getting-all-variables-in-scope)

Answer (score -1):

It might be easier if you put the possibly-undefined items onto a particular object. For example, this won't give you a hard time:

```
const stuff = {
    one: 1, 
    two: 2, 
    four: 4
}

let count = {
    one: stuff["one"],
    two: stuff["two"],
    three: stuff["three"],
    four: stuff["four"]
}

console.log(count)
```

Comment: That made it:
{ one: 1, two: 2, three: undefined, four: 4 }
Which was one of my defined methods that I cannot have...

Comment: Sorry, you want the three to disappear, or to be undefined?

Comment: The thing is, once you have it in the object form it is already:

const stuff = {
    one: 1, 
    two: 2, 
    four: 4
}
so that's just your starting place. Can you give an example of how you would want to manipulate it from that starting place?

Comment: If three is undefined, I need it to not create the property...  I am trying to stuff a bunch of variables into a single object, but some of the variables might be undefined.  To which, I cannot have them in the object.

Comment: If these are keys on an object, say "A", I think it is trivial because you already have object A and it only has the keys you want. You can list them with Object.keys() . If they are just variables in a script, is it possible that you don't know whether those variables exist?

Comment: That is correct, I do not know if the variables exist.  The variables are assigned via a web page which may or may not have the element.  Thus it would be undefined if the element did not exist.

Comment: Ah ok. Can you define the potential variables as undefined prior to the webpage? Something like this:

let x;

const y = {}
if (x !== undefined) {
    y["x"] = x
}

console.log(y)

Comment: I've decided to make them null and just clench my teeth at the messy object...  maybe I can find a way to 'forEach - delete' the nulls, or something.

Comment: Final Code Ended up Being:
( x => x && Object.keys(x) && ( x = JSON.string(x) ) && sessionStorage.setItem('e', (encode) ? btoa(x) : x) )({ one, two, three, four });