# Transform variables in JSON format with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, json

I have these JS variables:

```
var var1 = 'Banana';
var var2 = 'Apple';
var var3 = 'Cherry';
```

How can I transform, them in JSON like this ?

```
{
    var1:"Banana",
    var2:"Apple",
    var3:"Cherry"
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `const obj = { var1, var2, var3 };`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shorthand Method to Create Property in Object only if Variable is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67542545/shorthand-method-to-create-property-in-object-only-if-variable-is-defined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript provides JSON.stringify for serialization in JSON and JSON.parse for reading from JSON.

```
const json = JSON.stringify({ var1, var2, var3 });
```