# Can I get A list of classes based on my current scope

Tags: javascript, syntax, scope

For example, when I define two classes inside a function, can I somehow get a list of classes that were declared on the same level?

```
function a(){
 
   class Class1{ }

   class Class2{ }

   console.log(/*something*/ ); //result: Class1, Class2


}

a();
```

Comment: I keep seeing a lot of questions tagged javascript + typescript, even when typescript is not really used. Is microsoft polluting learners?

Comment: Please create a variable and assign an array of classes to this variable

Comment: No, just in my project using both and for me doesn't matter on with one lang we will discuss it.

Comment: It's the main question, how can I get the list. Based only on the scope. Without any arrays/object etc. (as a source code) that will contain enumeration of all classes.

Comment: there is no way to do it clean or natively. the only **horrible** option is to get the string representation of `a()` function (`a.toString()`) and then parse that string. Not really a good solution though.

Comment: This parser might help you: https://esprima.org/ please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25473571/5334486